# Making embedded YouTube videos start loading before playing

Tags: youtube

I am embedding a YouTube video in my website. Is it possible to make the clip start loading before the user presses play?

(I would *not* like the video to start playing automatically.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd probably have to write your own YouTube player to do it. They have coded it this way on purpose; it really cuts down on the bandwidth on YouTube's servers. Think about all the people that might visit a site, but not click the button...they would still download the file anyways, wasting both their and Google's bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

Make start automatically and after a second pause it. I don't know how to do it but there's a chrome extension or firefox addon which does it.